# angularjs filter by parent index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I need to put rows into tables depending on table index like:

```
<table ng-repeat="park in parks track by $index">
 <tr ng-repeat="process in processes | process.park=$parent.$index">
```

process is an object, and I need to compare process.park with index of table.

Comment: `ng-repeat="process in processes | filter : { park: $parent.$index }"`

Answer (score 2):

assign an index to a variable instead using `$parent`.

use `ng-if` to validate the index

```
<table ng-repeat="park in parks track by $index" ng-init="parentIndex = $index">
 <tr ng-repeat="process in processes" ng-if="process.park=parentIndex">
```